# Capture event like "Show touches/Pointer location"

Tags: android, android-ndk, touch-event

Is there a way to capture touch event not in my own activity, as when you enable Show touches and/or Pointer location in Developper options of your device ?
I searched on the web but it seems that this is not possible  with the JDK, but do you think it's possible with the NDK ?

Comment: Inside your app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279182/android-how-to-register-ontouchevent-for-entire-activity-main-content-view - Globally? No. Free keylogger for the NSA

Comment: No, not in my own app...

Comment: Nope - the NDK is actually quite limited compared to the SDK (Although using JNI its possible to call java code).

Comment: NDK can access the data if the device is rooted: [parse `/dev/input`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971435/parse-dev-input-event-touch-events). Normal apps can't access the input devices since they don't have the required permissions (only uid:root gid:input). And the only way to become part of "input" is to get [`android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/etc/platform.xml) which is not granted to regular apps.